# jsReport doesn't display correct names of a chart using Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts, jsreport

I am using Highcharts on jsReport for exporting .pdf document in which I include pie charts.

When I generate .pdf document, labels of the pie chart don't display correctly. There are only "i" and "l" characters. I have no idea where to look for the problem.

code on jsReport:

```
<script>
    var graphs = {{{toJSON graphs}}};
                for(var i=0; i<graphs.length; i++){
                   Highcharts.chart(graphs[i].id, {
                    chart: {
                        type: 'pie'
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: graphs[i].title
                    },
                    subtitle: {
                        text: graphs[i].subtitle
                    },
                    series: [{
                        showInLegend: true,
                        animation: false,
                        data: graphs[i].serie,
                        color: graphs[i].color,
                    }]
                });
            }
     </script>
```

Screenshot of generated pdf with charts, including name:"Slovenija" in first chart resulting in: [charts on pdf document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3UAIU.png)

I tried assigning data name like: name: "iiiiii", and it would result in displaying "iiiiii".

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor like jsfiddle? Try to use sample data with the same structure as in your production code.

Comment: Already fixed the issue. Forgot to add a comment.
Problem was with label transparency in my document. I used chartjs instead of HighCharts and it worked.